# Symmetry of Lorenz System

Tags: dynamical-systems, nonlinear-system

This is one idea I haven't quite understood how to apply.

The Lorenz system:

$\dot{x}=\sigma\left ( y-x \right )$

$\dot{y}=rx-y-xz$

$\dot{z}=-bz+xy$

I have worked out all the fixed points.

I would like to show that the system is reversible under

$x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto -y$

I.e, system is symmetric under an inversion through the z-axis.

Should I be substituting all the above RHS equation by $x \mapsto -x$ and $y \mapsto -y$? I haven't read through Strogaz text and he handwaved quite a fair bit without providing the meat of the technicality.

Any explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: yes you should also do it for LHS that is the derivatives,right :) so when you do we get back the same equations again!

Comment: Also if you are interested in Non Linear dynamics you can try [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55403/dynamical-systems-and-chaos-theory) chat room,although I admit that it is not so active.

Comment: Note that while reversible systems are also [equivariant](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Equivariant_dynamical_systems), your example is not a reversible system. Equivariant one, with a symmetry mentioned in the question, but not reversible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When $x \mapsto -x , y \mapsto -y $ then

$-\dot{x} = \sigma((-y) - (-x))$

$-\dot{y} = r(-x) - (-y) - (-x)(z)$

$\dot{z} = -bz + (-x)(-y)$

Which are the same Lorenz equations.

Also if you want a more reference,a matrix based approach you can refer 
http://planetmath.org/naturalsymmetryofthelorenzequation

Enjoy learning Lorenz equations :)

Comment: What happens when there is an added condition $t \mapsto -t$  to the ones in the OP?

Comment: Which added condition? in the OP?

Comment: Suppose we have $x \mapsto -x$, $y \mapsto -y$ and $t \mapsto -t$ where x,y and z are function of t. What changes?

Comment: Are you talking about negative time? I am not sure,also we cannot find closed form solution for $x,y,z$ , and if you are considering it as  a general question then it depends on whether $x(t),y(t),z(t)$ are even,odd function or neither but in this case of Lorenz equation I don't think that  will help as we donot know the equations for $x,y,z$.

Comment: Understood. But if we have $t \mapsto -t$ then substitute all time variable t in x ,y and z by -t, right?

Comment: Yes perhaps as per the above comment question you should substitute it in as $-x(-t),-y(-t),z(-t)$.

Answer (score 2):

Let us set $x = -X$, $y = -Y$, and $z = Z$. Thus, $\dot{x} = -\dot{X}$, $\dot{y} = -\dot{Y}$, and $\dot{z} = \dot{Z}$. The Lorenz system in terms of $\lbrace x, y , z\rbrace$ rewrites as
$$
\left\lbrace
\begin{aligned}
& \dot{X} = \sigma \left( Y - X \right) \\
& \dot{Y} = rX - Y - XZ \\
& \dot{Z} = -bZ + XY
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
in terms of $\lbrace X, Y , Z\rbrace$, which is the same differential system as before.